# Lubas & Sohn 12 bass button chromatic

Tags: chromatic, accordion

The 12 bass wooden chromatic box has loose reeds that I wish to repair.  Is there a schematic so that I know where the reeds should be placed?  The bass side reeds differ in sound going in and out with the bellows.  The right side stays the same.

Thank You

Mike

Comment: Assuming this is an accordion, I've added the accordion tag.

Comment: This is more of a specialty question. A good source for answers to this specific problem is https://www.accordionists.info. Several members of this site are involved in repair and would be helpful in identifying the instrument. As with any instrument of any caliber, unless you are an artisan yourself, you will be more successful by paying someone qualified in doing the work.